# Videos not appearing in Aframe

Tags: video, aframe

I can not get my video to play, it only appears as a black rectangle. I have tried viewing the video example on the AFrame website, and it is the same issue. I have tried viewing it in chrome, safari and mobile, all with the same result.I have implemented the fix for viewing on ios mobile, but it has not helped. I have also tried using a plane for the video and without a plane. Any help is appreciated

https://glitch.com/~mangrove-spotty-jump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Video `url` is not correct. See glitch assets and click on file to obtain url
2. Don't need to import the animation component. Use A-Frame [built-in animation](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/animation.html#sidebar)

[Corrected glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/curly-lapis-nigella?path=index.html:10:0)

Video auto plays as expected on desktop. On iOS / mobile [needs to call videoEl.play() within a click / tap handler](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/introduction/faq.html#why-does-my-video-not-play-on-mobile) Notice that video renders but it's paused. Only first frame is visible.